# What permissions should the database file and settings.py have in a django app running on apache

Tags: django, apache, ubuntu, sqlite

I'm running an app using apache, django and sqlite3. What permissions do the database file and settings.py need to have in order for the app to run correctly?

Comment: The issue is that the database file and settings.py file were set to readonly to prevent overwriting them during a `git pull`. I would like to make changes now but I don't want to change the permissions on these files in such a way that causes problems for the site that is running via apache.

Answer (score 0):

All the files need to be accessible by the user the Apache httpd daemon uses. Check the *User* directive of your configuration. Make sure the sqlite file is writable by that user.